# Strip all non alphabetic characters from beginning of Python string w/o using RegEx

Tags: python, string

I have various word list out of which many are noisy. By noisy I mean it begins with some non alphabetic characters like ' " ', ' - ' . e.g.: "thisword, -thisword , -"this word, .thisword and can be several others.

Like we can remove ascii by using

```
from string import ascii letter
string.lstrip(ascii_letters)
```

is there any similar method in python that can handle non_ascii without using regular expression?

Thanks!

Comment: I love them but the constraint here with the problem is on regex :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why dont you use the [string.puctuation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.punctuation)

```
>>> from string import punctuation
>>> "-asdf".lstrip(punctuation)
'asdf'
>>> "'asdf".lstrip(punctuation)
'asdf'
>>> '"asdf'.lstrip(punctuation)
'asdf'
>>> ',asdf'.lstrip(punctuation)
'asdf'
```

Comment: Although wont work for all but suits best to my data. Thanks!

Comment: @MrinalKumar You are welcome :) Could you specify cases where it may fail. So that we could think of some way around

Comment: Some of the data that i found out later were like "thisword<p>" so i had to explicitly handle that ; i am sure that is not the best way. I am not sure how to do that.

Comment: Also I thought it wont work for non punctuation symbols but I am mostly wrong on that as it works for almost all the symbol in my data other than cases i mentioned above. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

using `itertools.dropwhile`:

```
>>> def removes(s):
...     return "".join(itertools.dropwhile(lambda x:not x.isalnum(),s))
... 
>>> removes("---thisword")
'thisword'
>>> removes("-^--thisword")
'thisword'
>>> removes("thisword")
'thisword'
>>> removes("...thisword")
'thisword'
```

Answer (score 2):

Keeps only alphabets in word

```
"".join([x for x in word if x.isalpha()])
```

Answer (score 1):

Negate character set:

```
>>> from string import ascii_letters
>>> non_letter = ''.join(set(map(chr, range(128))) - set(ascii_letters))
>>> s = '-hello'
>>> s.lstrip(non_letter)
'hello'
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest a while loop that trims each string until it hits an ascii. Load the non asciis into a list then search until you hit an ascii. Implement it as a function so that you can effectively abstract away the task.

Hope that helps.